# CSS3 translateY slide?

Tags: jquery, css, transform

When I click the button, I want the slide (initially set at height 0) to slide down. What am I missing here?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kpqagj4u/

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    $('div').css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'translateY(' 100% ')',
        '-moz-transform'    : 'translateY(' 100% ')',
        '-ms-transform'     : 'translateY(' 100% ')',
        '-o-transform'      : 'translateY(' 100% ')',
        'transform'         : 'translateY(' 100% ')'
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 0;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 2s cease;
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: How you are retrieving the id?

Comment: So you need **posts** slug in place of id? Is the id will change later?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to exclude a category based on a category slug, only the id.